# Load Data From DataTable to Sql with sql batch update

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ms-access, datatable, sql-update

I have a MS Access database with 5 tables but I am interested in moving two tables into SQL Server via a C# console application:

[image]

I created a connection string and a `DataTable` for itemmaster and was successful in moving the data from the MS Access database into the data table:

```
namespace AccessDBtoSql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string straccessconnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= T:\Aravind\Company Master Data.accdb";

            string strItemMasterSelect = "SELECT * FROM [Item Master]";
            DataSet DataSet1 = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;

            try
            {
                myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(straccessconnection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {

                OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strItemMasterSelect, myAccessConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

                myAccessConn.Open();
                myDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet1, "itemmaster");
                DataTable itemmaster;
                itemmaster = DataSet1.Tables["itemmaster"];
                foreach (DataRow drcurrent in itemmaster.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11} {12} {13} {14} {15} {16} {17} {18} {18} {19} {20} {21} {22} {23} {24} {25} {26} {27} {28} {29} {30} {31} {32} {33} {34} {35} {36} {37} {38} {39} {40} {41} {42} {43} {44} {45} {46} {47} {48} {49} {50} {51} {52} {53} {54} {55} {56} {57} {58} {59} {60} {61} {62} {63} {64} {65} {66} {67} {68} {69} {70} {71} {72} {73} {74} {75} {76} {77} {78} {79} {80} {81} {82} {83} {84} {85} {86} {87} {88} {89} {90} {91} {92} {93} {94} {95} {96} {97} {98} {99} {100} {101} {102} {103} {104} {105} {106} {107} {108} {109} {110} {111} {112} {113} {114} {115} {116}",
                        drcurrent["Item"].ToString(),
                        drcurrent["Description"].ToString(),
                        drcurrent["Item Type"].ToString(),
                         drcurrent["Item Group"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Product Type"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Selection Code"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Standard Cost Price"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Inventory Unit"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Purchase Price"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Purchase Price Unit"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Latest Purchase Price"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sales Price"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sales Price Unit"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Phantom"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Scrap Factor"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Weight"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Signal Code"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Cost Price Component"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Last CP Trans Date"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Unit Set"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Inventory on Hand"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Purchase Unit"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sales Unit"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Price Group"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Statistics Group"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Commission Group"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Rebate Group"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sugg Ret Price"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Units per Carton"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Gross Weight"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Net Weight"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Freight Class"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Unit UPC"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Case UPC"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Retail/Misc only"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Additional Block"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Display Boxes"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Best Before"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Reportable"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Package (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Package"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Style (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Style"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Heart (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Heart"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Basket (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Basket"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sugar Free (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sugar Free"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Flatback (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Flatback"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Multipack (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Multipack"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Displayer (Enum)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Displayer"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Cross Shippable"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Freezer Item"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Novelty Flag"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Normal/Special/Multipack"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #1"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #1Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #2"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #2Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #3"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #3Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #4"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #4Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #5"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #5Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #6"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #6Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #7"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #7Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #8"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #8Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #9"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #9Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #10"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #10Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #11"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #11Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #12"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #12Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #13"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #13Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #14"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #14Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #15"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #15Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #16"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #16Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #17"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #18"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #18Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #19"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #19Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #20"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Component #20Units"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Unit Weight lbs"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Unit Weight ozs"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Unit Weight Grams"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Prepriced"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Country of Sale"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Egg"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Pallet Spec  Wrapped"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Pallet Spec  Non-Wrapped"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Stack Height"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Scan Unit UPC (SO/PO)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Budget Category"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Budget Category description"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Base Item"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["registered Item"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Material"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Size"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Standard"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Sales Price (CAD)"].ToString(),
            drcurrent["Suggested Retail Price (CAD)"].ToString());
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                myAccessConn.Close();
            }
```

The above query gave me this result:

[image]

Which is correct but now I need to move all the data from the data table into SQL Server and I am stuck here. I am trying to implement a SQL batch update that begins a transaction would update 10,000 records at a time and commit if all goes well if not rollback transaction.

What I have so far:

```
public void sqlbatchupdatelocal()
{
    string strsqlconnection = "Data Source=KCMJF1XTR1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AccessMaster1;Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strsqlconnection))
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me finish the SQL update on the code above, I want to take all the 55885 records from itemmaster data table but load 10000 records at a time into SQL Server. If I get this working then I will follow the same approach for the other table as well.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlBulkCopy`by using column mapping function and set `BatchSize` to 10,000. here is good example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy